# Google places API not returning next_page_token Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm calling Google places API with the call,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?radius=10000&sensor=false&key=MYKEY&location=21.1700,72.8300&types=bank";
```

I've set 5s delay before second call but first call itself is not returning next_page_token.
What should I do?

Another problem
If I try to write types=bank|cafe then eclipse would throw Illegal Argument Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I just performed the same search and `next_page_token` is returned as the second field.

I had the same problem with the pipe character in [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets).  I [solved it](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/sprockets/google/Places.java#L823) by URL encoding the pipe as `%7C`.